# InitializeService no longer being called, can't work out why

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I've got an odata wcf service and it looks like InitializeService is not being called...

The code looks like:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class MyDataService : DataService<MyContext>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }

    // see http://romiller.com/2010/07/19/ef-ctp4-tips-tricks-wcf-data-service-on-dbcontext/
    protected override AzureAppContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        var ctx = base.CreateDataSource();

        // Disable proxy object creation.
        ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

When this runs I get an exception reported like:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'On data context type 'MyContext', there is a top
>   IQueryable property 'MyEntities' whose element type is not an entity
>   type. Make sure that the IQueryable property is of entity type or
>   specify the IgnoreProperties attribute on the data context type to
>   ignore this property.'. See server logs for more details

In this case, MyEntities is an EntityFramework Code First DBSet.

If I place `[IgnoreProperties("MyEntities")]` on the context, then the error is thrown on the second property set instead.

Key I think: If I put a breakpoint in the InitializeService method then it doesn't look like it's being called.

Really not sure what is happening right now...

Comment: The error says the issue is your data context, and specifically the IQueryable<T> set 'MyEntities', what is the type T of 'MyEntities'? Is it an EntityObject or a Linq-2-SQL object? POCO? That information would be helpful. Its probably a problem with metadata provided for T and the service not being able to use it. I've read elsewhere that it may need a primary key or [DataServiceKey] attribute.

Comment: It's an EF Code First entity. I've actually transferred the code across from a working project... The problem here is definitely that the InitializeService method isn't being called - I just can't work out why! Current suspicions are web.config, project settings, some Azure service reference includes,... I'm sure it'll be something obvious when I get there... I've clarified entity type in the question now (thanks!)

Comment: Make sure that the entity has a primary key defined, that could be the issue.

Comment: Sean - please post this answer "The problem could be that you haven't got a DataServiceKey defined"... and I'll happily tick it. What the problem was... when I took the files across from one project to another the stylecop rules insisted that the primary keys changed from "EntityID" to "EntityId"... now this didn't matter for EF as I had "[Key]" defined plus customer mapping rules... However, for the oData service this was terminal - and also really hard to spot! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sean helped identify the correct answer in the comments above.

Basically what had happened was that when I imported the project, then stylecop adjusted my key names from EntityID to EntityId.

Within the SQL EF layer this was OK - because I had mappings set up for the keys. However, within the oData Service it was looking for names ending in "ID" (case sensitive) and when it didn't find them it barfed without explanation - not making it easy to debug!